# How to properly give actors a unique sensible name

Tags: scala, akka

By default in Akka actors get a name like '$a', or '$a.$oi.$abc' when they are nested. So it makes sense to give them a proper name so you at least can see some sensible name in the logs.
But ... there can only be one actor with a given name. So how to give actors a sensible but unique name?

I have already experienced that suffixing the name with a millisecond timestamp is not sufficient. It still results in duplicate name exceptions. These is a way to get a nano-timestamp, but I have read getting it is expensive.

It would be nice if the default Akka naming could be used, but suffixed or prefixed with a custom name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can increment some counter and use it any time you create new actor.

```
var counter = 0
val a = actorSystem.actorOf(Props[MyActorClass], s"actor-$counter")
counter += 1
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing in a project now, but the problem is that I then get counters all over the place. On other hand, trying to put it at a central place would the possible lead to concurrency issues.

Comment: Just use AtomicInteger or AtomicLong instead of Int

Answer (score 0):

Create hierarchy of actors with `context.actorOf(...)`. So you can easily avoid collisions.